# Remove var object from memory in titanium

Tags: javascript, android, ios, garbage-collection, titanium

I have one .js file with a window and then I add all my layouts to this window.

**first.js**

```
var Win = Ti.UI.CreateWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'white'
});
Win.open();
```

**secun.js**

```
var View = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    width : deviceWidth,
    backgroundColor : 'white'
});

Ti.UI.CurrentWindow.add(View);

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "Test",
    color : 'white',
    height : deviceHeight * 0.090,
    width : deviceWidth,
    backgroundColor : 'transparent',
    textAlign : 'center',
    font : {
        fontSize : deviceHeight * 0.0285,
        fontWeight : 'normal'
    }
});

View.add(label);
```

To remove the View I make as follow:

```
Ti.UI.CurrentWindow.remove(View);
```

When I due this, the memory occupied by the View and label are released or is it necessary to doe something else to release the phone memory? Like setting variables to null so the are no longer associates do Ti object and can be cleaned by the garbage collector?

The problem of seething variables to null in my project relays in the fact that some variables are created inside functions and then are not available outside that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do not want to access any view or label, then do not create a variable for  it. For eg. if you are not accessing `label` anywhere else (just adding it on `View`), then it is recommended that you directly add the `label` as :

```
View.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "Test",
    color : 'white',
    height : deviceHeight * 0.090,
    width : deviceWidth,
    backgroundColor : 'transparent',
    textAlign : 'center',
    font : {
        fontSize : deviceHeight * 0.0285,
        fontWeight : 'normal'
    }
}));
```

for more please have a look into http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Managing_Memory_and_Finding_Leaks
http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/27/memory-management/

Comment: And how can I release the memory of variables that I have created and need to access in other places of my function?

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues for that you can also use the`removeAllChildren()` method of a view before removing that view. http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-removeAllChildren